ggstatsplot is not creating the p-value and bracket between the comparison
I am trying to add the p-value and bracket to this following plot.
However, the bracket with the p value is not created:
generate_EDSS <- function(n) {
vals <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 0.5)
# Randomly sample from the values
sample(vals, size = n, replace = TRUE)
}
df <- tibble(
id = paste0("id", 1:80), # Create "id" values based on numbers
neda = factor(sample(c("No", "Yes"), size = 80, replace = TRUE)),
Evaluation = rep(c("baseline", "followup"), each = 40), # Two values for Evaluation
EDSS = generate_EDSS(80) # Generate EDSS values
)

ggwithinstats(
data = df,
x    = Evaluation, 
y    = EDSS, 
type = "nonparametric",
pairwise.display = "all",
p.adjust.method = "bonferroni",
xlab = c("Time of Evaluation"),
digits = 3,
package = "ggsci",
palette = "nrc_npg",
violin.args = list(width = 0),
) 


Looks like they only automatically plot the ggsignif::geom_signif() layer when you have more than two groups. However, they apparently set up the aesthetic mapping nicely so you can just manually add that layer and at least for this example, it seems to inherit the correct calculated p-value. Try adding + ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = list(c(1, 2))) or + ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("baseline", "followup"))) See this Github issue: https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/issues/605 However, ggsignif calculate its own pvals so it may not always match up

Pairwise comparisons make sense only when there are more than two groups. ggstatsplot will carry out this analysis and display them if there are more than two groups.
